# Finding multiple set of given words in a paragraph array

Tags: java, arrays, search, find

I'm searching for word(s) in a string array and if found I want to return their line.
I have tried to divide the searched input in an array and then search it in the paragraph array line by line. Which does not really work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String paragraph[] = new String[10];
            String toBeSearched;
            String curSearch;
            boolean intIndex = false ;
            paragraph[0] = "Hello my name is";
            paragraph[1] = "Jack the reaper";
            paragraph[2] = "what up";
            
            System.out.printf("enter string:");
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            toBeSearched = myScanner.nextLine();
           
        String[] divide = toBeSearched.split(" ");
        
       
        for(int j = 0 ;j <=10 ; j++) {
            
            curSearch = divide[j];
            
            for (int k = 0; k <=paragraph[j].length() ; k++) {
                    
                    intIndex = paragraph[j].contains(curSearch);

                    if(intIndex == true) {
                        System.out.printf("Found at line %d \n",j );        
                    } 
            }   

        }
```

Assuming I can search for at most 10 words at a time.

Lets say user enters : "Hello name the up"
I want the answer : At line 1
At line 1
At line 2
At line 3

If I ask for a word in the 2nd or the 3rd index of the paragraph it does not work I dont understand why (getting no error messages)

Comment: The size of **divide** array is unknown and basically can change every time user enters a sentence.With the ` for(int j = 0 ;j <=10 ; j++)` you are assuming that the size of this array is 10 but it is not.What if the user enters **Hello From Stackoverflow*** now the size of ***divide*** array will be 3 and going with that for logic of the for loop it will come to the point that you will try to index the 4th..10th element of the ***divide*** array which they don't exist because the size of array is 3 not 10 . Change `for(int j = 0 ;j <=10 ; j++) {` to `for(int j = 0 ;j <divie.length ; j++) {`

Comment: @Typhon thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code compare it to yours and figure out the issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args)


{
     String paragraph[] = {"Hello my name is","Jack the reaper", "what up"};
     String toBeSearched;
     String curSearch;
     boolean intIndex = false ;
    
     
     System.out.printf("enter string:");
     Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     toBeSearched = myScanner.nextLine();
    
 String[] divide = toBeSearched.split(" ");
 

 for(int i = 0; i < divide.length ; i ++) {
     String word = divide[i];
     for(int y = 0; y < paragraph.length ; y++) {
         if(paragraph[y].contains(word)) {
             System.out.println(word+ "found at line: "+ y);
         }
     }
     
 }
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much!!